# Can I recover the events deleted from my phone local calendar?

Tags: backup, recovery-mode, calendar, bugs, lg

I have an LG P700.

Yesterday I tried to use LG PC Suite to back it up. PC Suite got stuck at some point of the process and asked me to disconnect the phone and restart it, in spite that the screen of the phone had a warning not to touch it. I rashly followed the PC Suite instructions and restarted the phone. After doing so, I found that no backup had been created and all the events in Google Calendar had disappeared. Everything else in the phone seems to be working fine. I was using the phone local calendar, and I didn't have it synchronized to the cloud.

About an hour before I started the PC Suite backup I set up the Backup & Reset options for my Google account (Settings -> Backup & Reset), so I understand that the phone started to back up itself automatically at that point. I don't know if this might help.

So, is there any way to recover my lost events? I'm really crossing my fingers here 'cause I lost around 400 - 500 events.

Comment: What calendar? Is it entirely local or something like Google Calendar that is on the cloud? If it is local you MIGHT be able to use a recovery tool for deleted data but I wouldn't be too sure about it to be honest.

Comment: Entirely local. I have updated the original question. That idea about the recovery tool sounds interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ability to restore deleted entries really varies from each calendar.

Assuming you made your entries to Google Calendar and didn't sync it to the cloud, then no it's not possible to restore it.